# How to use .loc function to collect data from certain rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot data from specific rows of a .csv file based on the input of the user. The first column of the data file is a unique ID value and the following three columns are the x,y,z values to be plotted.

Once the user inputs one of the ID values, how do I only plot the x, y, z data of all of the rows with the same ID value as the input ID value?

I have been trying to use .loc but have not had any success.

```
input_id = int(input())
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df = df.loc[df['id column'] == input_id]
```

[Example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXHds.png)

Comment: What are you trying to plot? Do you have a code written for which kind of plot do you want to plot?

Comment: I have been using Axes3D from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d for the 3D plots. I haven't had any issues with that. My goal is to be able to plot all of the rows of data where the ID is 01 for example. Up to this point, I would have had to save all of the data associated with ID 01 into a different .csv in order for me to plot it. I am trying to get rid of that step and just have the program plot the data based on the ID value that I input.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data?

Comment: I just added an example to the problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Call plot of your df

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = df.loc[df['id column'] == input_id]
df[['columns_to_plot']].plot() # assuming it's x, y ,z
plt.show()
```

Check the doc for plotting types: [dataframe.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: I haven't had any problems plotting the data and generating the plot. I am having problems with telling the program exactly which columns to plot. Instead of creating a new .csv with only the rows that I want plotted, I want to tell the program to only plot the rows where the ID is the same as the input ID.

Comment: Does the `columns_to_plot` change depending on the input ID?

Comment: No, the columns being plotted will be the same no mater the input ID. I just want to plot certain rows of data instead of the entire collection of data.

Comment: the `loc` function will slice your df into a smaller one that you can plot, I'm not sure what you are missing

Answer (score 1):

Use a condition/mask and .loc to select only the rows you want, then drop the rest, and finally plot the dataframe.

```
condition = (df['id column'] == input_id)
df = df.loc[condition].dropna()
df.plot(kind='line',x='index',y='value')
plt.show()
```